# Navigation tabs with jQuery mobile similar to Google Play store

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, tabs

How can I do this type of navigation tabs with jQuery mobile, similar to the Google Play store?

[image: example]

Comment: what have u tried till now? show us some code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use swipe events and with jquery dynamically switch between parts of you html using toggle, or using $.mobile.changePage(url), example

```
$('div[data-role=page]').on('swipeleft, swiperight ', go);

function go(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
        case 'swiperight':
            console.log('swiperight');
            $('#divid2,#divid3').toggle(false);
            $('#divid1').toggle(true);
            break;
        case 'swipeleft':
            console.log('swipeleft');
            $('#divid1,#divid2').toggle(false);
            $('#divid3').toggle(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

Something like that or you can use jquery animate to fadeOut parts of the html, or use $.mobile.changePage(url) which can transition between different pages and it will look like tabs if you have same headers and footers.

Comment: Can you please make code pen for it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            <a href="#page-1">Page 1</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-3" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 3 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("a[data-role=tab]").each(function () {
    var anchor = $(this);
    anchor.bind("click", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(anchor.attr("href"), {
            transition: "none",
            changeHash: false
        });
        return false;
    });
});

$("div[data-role=page]").bind("pagebeforeshow", function (e, data) {
    $.mobile.silentScroll(0);
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.transition = 'slide';
});
```

For further info check

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html