# how to show div with slide in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have Exactly same Question .
[Navigation tabs with jQuery mobile similar to Google Play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584627/navigation-tabs-with-jquery-mobile-similar-to-google-play-store.I) am trying to move one tap another using swipe left and swipe right with slide effect.but I am not able to do that .can you please tell me how we can slide as in Google app store.
Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ua3zkvwj/5/

```
$('div[data-role=page]').on('swipeleft, swiperight ', go);

function go(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
        case 'swiperight':
            console.log('swiperight');
            $('#registrationPage,#faqPage').toggle(false);
            $('#loginPage').toggle(true);
            break;
        case 'swipeleft':
            console.log('swipeleft');
            $('#loginPage,#registrationPage').toggle(false);
            $('#faqPage').toggle(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

I need user can't see white screen as we use scroll or swipe js plugin ?

Comment: Did you try this? http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/swipe-page/  http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/transitions/

Comment: but I think it show some white screen in between transition.can you change in my fiddle.

Comment: @Dipaks give some fiddle so that it better understanding

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fRb9L/2/

Comment: @ezanker it is not good solution ..it is showing white screen when moving one tab to another

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: Remove comma between events `("swipeleft swiperight")`.

Comment: No sir Actually it is showing white screen when slide please check fiddle @ezanker

Comment: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified and http://jsfiddle.net/jPneT/208/ both example no white screen

Comment: user2535959 But how you implement on ezanker example or my example..could you please this plugin in my fiddle or ezanker plugin.